# How to add fade-in animation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uikit

I want to add a fade-in animation to a `UILabel`. I tried it out by adding a extension in UIView for both fade-in and fade-out animations. The fade-out animation works well but I am having trouble with fade-in animation.

Here is my code,

```
extension UIView{

func fadeIn() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
        self.alpha = 1.0
    }, completion: nil)

}

func fadeOut() {
      UIView.animate(withDuration: 8.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
                    self.alpha = 0.0
                    }, completion: nil)
            }
        }

 class myScene: UIViewController {

 let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400))

 override func viewDidLoad(){

 super.viewDidLoad()

    self.label.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width / 2, y: self.view.frame.height / 2 )
    self.label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 100)
    self.label.textAlignment = .center
    self.label.text = "Hello"

  //self.view.addSubview(label) (tried adding this after and before the fadein() statement)

    label.fadeIn()
 }
}
```

I believe I am making a silly mistake but somehow can't figure out what. Please help me figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the label alpha to 0 in the interface builder?

You call `label.fadeIn()` in viewDidLoad() but if the alpha is already 1 then nothing will happen

EDIT---------

You cannot call it like so

```
override func viewDidLoad(){ 
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.label.alpha = 0 
    self.label.fadeIn()
}
```

This will not work.

What you need to do is call the fade in on view will appear like so.

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.label.alpha = 0
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.label.fadeIn()
}
```

EDIT ---------

Since you are using playgrounds. I would recommend to NOT use it, the functionality is not the same always as a regular project. You can normally apply the ALPHA on the interface builder.. but not in playgrounds. 
So your labels will always have alpha 1 no matter what.

You will not be able to achieve what you want using playgrounds. Meaning, on load have the label fade in. You can do this on a button or action click ?

You can also try this on viewDidAppear instead

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.label.fadeIn()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am currently working in Swift Playgrounds. I tried setting the alpha to zero as `self.label.alpha = 0.0` in `viewDidLoad()` before `label.fadeIn()` but nothing changed.

Comment: @AtharvSalokhe this will not work. check my updated answer.

Comment: @AtharvSalokhe made error in viewWillAppear, forgot to add in the animated

Comment: @AtharvSalokhe its because you are using Playgrounds. Never use playgrounds in my opinion. The behaviour of the playground is different then a regular project. Check updated answer.